# Clipping two shapefiles results in missing features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip

I want to clip a shapefile to fit another and when I do parts of my map end up missing.  [image: Map With Layers]

Any thoughts?
(Clipping census shapefile (blue) to a custom shapefile (grey))

Comment: Have you checked the geometry of both layers?

Comment: how would I go about checking? From what I can see by toggling the layers they're both in good shape but when I clip them I get this same result.

Comment: Vector - geometry tools - check geometry. Geometry errors can cause clips and other processes to fail.

Comment: In addition to what @SpatialSuccess suggested, if you did find errors then using `v.clean` from the **Processing Toolbox** could help repair your data. If you still have problems, you could consider uploading your shapefiles to a public server so that others could test it.

Comment: Which bit is missing, is it Treasure Island (top right?) If that's missing in your grey layer, the clip would remove that.

Comment: @StevenKay the grey areas should be blue (Marina, some of the Presidio and South Beach) excluding south of crocker amazon/Daly City.